# Хранения дат и часовые пояса

Tags: php, mysql

У меня в базе данных храниться дата добавления какого-либо объекта,причем,храниться она в формате UNIX. Пользователь видит дату в формате (День-месяц-год), тоесть без времени. В моем проекте правильная и корректная дата очень важна.
Но есть одна проблема. Например один пользователь добавил дату 22/04/2018 00:00 (GMT). Допустим,пользователь скажем с Украины запросил эту дату(22/04/2018 00:00 ). Всё хорошо, но его запрос тоже нужно перевести в GMT. И выходит, что в sql запрос пойдёт дата (21/04/2018 21:00). Повторюсь, все операции с датами происходят через их перевод в unix время. 
В конечном счете пользователь с Украины не увидит объекта з запрашиваемой датой,хотя, он ёё запросил.
Я уже потерял всякое понимание, как эти даты переводить и как работать с часовыми поясами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользователи добавляют данные в БД не с помощью прямого подключения к БД, а скорее всего через сайт, верно? То есть скрипт добавления/извлечения данных работает с одним и тем же часовым поясом (который на сервере, а не на часах посетителя), расхождений быть не должно.
Ну и при добавлении/извлечении есть способы указывать часовой пояс – используйте в скриптах всегда один и все будет нормально.